# Getting error with parallelize() of pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am getting an error while parallelizing data with the parallelize() function of pyspark. I am using spark 2.4.3 and python 3.7

```
data = [("James","Smith","USA","CA"),
        ("Michael","Rose","USA","NY"),
        ("Robert","Williams","USA","CA"),
        ("Maria","Jones","USA","FL")
      ]
    
columns = ["firstname","lastname","country","state"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
# df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data)
    
out = sc.parallelize(df)\
        .map(lambda x: (x,1))\
        .collect()
```

Here is the error stack:

```
    330                 raise Py4JError(
    331                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
--> 332                     format(target_id, ".", name, value))
    333         else:
    334             raise Py4JError(

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o93.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error is because you're trying to parallelize a pyspark DataFrame but instead it should be a local python collection (such as list, array etc). [Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=parallelize#pyspark.SparkContext) is the description of parallelize method as **Distribute a local Python collection to form an RDD. Using xrange is recommended if the input represents a range for performance.**.

You might be trying to do this instead:

```
out = df.rdd\
        .map(lambda x: (x,1))\
        .collect()
```